# django-import-export package get a Foreignkey value while Export to XL file

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

First pardon me for my bad english. I am very new in Django Framework. I want to Export a foreignkey value called `title` which is in 'Product' model. There is multiple Foreignkey Relations between different django app models. Please take a look below all of this models:

**products/models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=450)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(
        default=1000, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, help_text='20ml/20gm', null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, help_text='S/M/L/XL/32/34/36', null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**carts/models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    last_purchase_price = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=15)
    weight_avg_cost = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.0, max_digits=20, decimal_places=15)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

And my working models is **analytics/models.py**, from where I want to export the product `title` in XL sheet.

```
class AllReportModel(models.Model):
    # All report model
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ws_invoice = models.ForeignKey(WholesaleInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    stock_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and Finally **analytics/admin.py** is :

```
class AllReportModelResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = AllReportModel
        fields = ('id', 'invoice', 'ws_invoice', 'entry', 'stock_quantity')


    class AllReportModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = AllReportModelResource
        list_display = ['invoice', 'ws_invoice', 'entry', 'timestamp']
        search_fields = ['invoice']
    
    
    admin.site.register(AllReportModel, AllReportModelAdmin)
```

**Help will be highly appreciated.**

Comment: Provide `resources.py`

Comment: Don't have any `resources.py` file in my project

Comment: You need to create for `AllReportModelResource` class

Comment: can you able to clarify please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been into this situation before, its solution is very easy.

You can refer to `django-import-export` documentation for advanced data manipulation on export [Click HERE](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation-on-export).

Comment: wow.. thanks it worked !! .. i have an another question , when i export the csv ,the title comes in first , how can i put it in specific position in csv file ?? do you have any idea ?